# Index of the smallest number starting from a certain index

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the index of the smallest number but only after a certain point in the array.

The method that I'm working on is indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom.

I'm doing mooc.fi exercise 104.3, if you need more information go to http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-6?noredirect=1 and scroll down to exercise 104.

My question is, how do I start from, from example, index 2 in an array and ignore everything before it. I'm trying to find the smallest number in the array after the certain index.

My code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static int smallest(int[] array) {
        int[] sorted = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sorted[i] = array[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(sorted);
        return sorted[0];
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallest(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == smallest(array)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // This is the method here.
    public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == smallest(array)) {
                return indexOfTheSmallest(array);
            }
        }
        return 27;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // indexes:    0  1  2  3   4
        int[] values = {-1, 6, 9, 8, 12};
        System.out.println(indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(values, 1));
        System.out.println(indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(values, 2));
        System.out.println(indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(values, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the main post. I don't know what to do

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to start from a certain index and ignore everything before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your `smallest` method when implementing `indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom`, since the smallest element returned by `smallest` may be in the beginning of the array (i.e. in an index smaller than the passed `index`).

A much simpler implementation would be :

```
public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
    int minIndex = index;
    for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[minIndex]) {
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: Looking at OP's code that does not even start resembling a solution, do you think he's going to learn much from a clean, fully finished, solution to his exercise?

Comment: Yeah this works but I don't quite understand it completely

Comment: @syntax Well, you don't have to sort the array in order to find the index of the smallest element. You just have to iterate over the elements of the array starting at the given index, and keep track of the index holding the smallest number (whenever you find an index i such that `array[i] < array[minIndex]`, `i` becomes the new candidate for the index of the smallest number).

Comment: I understand now, I wrote down each iteration down on paper and it makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOfTheSmallest` is returning the **index** of the smallest element, while you are comparing it with the **element value** in `indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom`.

**==EDIT==**

See @Eran 's answer for a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to fix your code with as few as possible changes.

```
public class Main {

    public static int smallestFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        int[] sorted = new int[array.length-index];

        for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            sorted[i-index] = array[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(sorted);
        return sorted[0];
    }

    // This is the method here.
    public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        int smallest = smallestFrom( array, index);
        for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == smallest ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 27;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // indexes:    0  1  2  3   4
        int[] values = {-1, 6, 9, 8, 12};
        System.out.println(indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(values, 1));
        System.out.println(indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(values, 2));
        System.out.println(indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(values, 4));
    }
}
```

`smallest` method has been changed to `smallestFrom`. `smallestFrom` computes the smallest value starting from index. Does that by making a copied array which contains only the values from index till end of the array.
indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom first calls smallestFrom to get the smalles value in that subArray; then it iterates the array from index till it finds said smallest value. The index when the value is found is the one returned.

Eran's solution is way better. Less code and more efficient. This code exists only to help you get a better undestanding.